# Mule 3 Quartz timer alignment for near real-time processing

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a processing chain that needs to output data at the top of the second, i.e.

```
System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 == 0
```

within +/- 100 milliseconds.  So, I set a Quartz timer as follows;

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatInterval="1000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="publisher" startDelay="900">
    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

I notice that the time intervals are fairly steady at 1 second spacing, but the alignment within the second is random, probably depending on when the timer first starts.  For example, my last test run output times where

```
System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 == 449
```

I surmise the startDelay applies only to the very first interval.  I'm also guessing I might tweak timer alignment if I insert a custom interceptor that uses Thread.sleep to occassionaly tweak it. I.e., if it wakes at 449, Thread.sleep(451).   Or, I might set quartz to trigger every 50 milliseconds, and use the custom-interceptor to filter out events out of my desired time range.

Is there a cleaner 'purist' approach to getting Mule to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `repeatInterval` with a Cron expression that fires every seconds.

According to the syntax supported by Quartz described in the [user guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger), the following should work: `0/1 * * ? * *`